# Nexus 7 (2013) won’t go past Google logo screen, can't enter Recovery mode

Tags: nexus-7

I hold down the power button until it starts up, and it gets up to the Google logo screen, but won’t go any further; it just freezes on that screen.
Tried to reset device in Recovery Mode (support.google.com/nexus/answer/4596836?hl=en) using these steps:

1. If your tablet is on, turn it off.
2. Press & hold the Volume Down button, then press & hold the Power button simultaneously until the tablet turns on. You'll see the word "Start" with an arrow drawn around it.
3. Press the Volume Down button twice to highlight Recovery mode.
4. Press the Power button to start Recovery mode. You'll see an image of an Android robot with a red exclamation mark and the words "No command."
5. While holding down the Power button, press the Volume Up button.
6. Use the volume buttons to scroll to "wipe data/factory reset," then press the Power button to select it.
7. Scroll down to "Yes - erase all user data," then press the Power button to select it.

Points #1-#3 go well, but I can't pass through #4, after pressing the Power button to start Recovery Mode there is no 'image of an Android robot with a red exclamation mark', screen just goes off for 1-3 sec and than there is again Google logo screen, performing actions from #5 gives no result, tablet just goes off if I hold the Power button and the Volume Up button too long.

Comment: Are you rooted? I'm guessing not since you're running stock recovery?